# Same Event ID Received for Many Event Instances Facebook + WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, facebook, woocommerce, facebook-pixel

I use Facebook Pixel for WooCommerce site and in Event Manager of Facebook Business profile I see message about this issue:

> You're sending the same event ID for many instances of your AddToCart
> events. Event IDs are unique identifiers that are used to deduplicate
> identical events received from your pixel and the Conversions API so
> they're not counted twice. To ensure Facebook is accurately counting
> your events, each unique event instance needs its own unique event ID.
> This may cause issues with the measurement of your events and the
> attribution of your ad campaigns.

As far as I understand, eventID must be updated by JavaScript every time someone presses "Add to cart" button?

If it is right, where/when I should update this eventID?

If it is no, could you please tell what should I do to fix this issue?

(I am beginner in Facebook integrations and WooCommerce, so I am sorry if this question is too obvious)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sending ADDTOCART event via FB pixel JS as below. I'm adding a unique number in eventID so that each time this is called it should have different ID with it.

```
var random_num = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
    content_ids: ['1122', '3234'],
    content_type: 'product'
}, {eventID: "AddToCart_" + social_media_eventId + "_" + random_num});
```